# Didn't Understand which data type is name.gettext().tostring()

Tags: java, android, types

I am building an app that toastes Welcome when only specific email and password is inputted. Otherwise it says `Incorrect Email/password`. But I don't understand what the problem with my code is. I think the problem is within `string.gettext().toString()`. I do not know how to use it in the if-else-loop...

```
package com.example.project2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Project2 extends AppCompatActivity {

  public void login(View view) {
    EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
    Log.i("info","Button pressed!");

    String Email = email.getText().toString();
    String Password = password.getText().toString();

    boolean email1 = Email.contains("example876@gmail.com");
    boolean password1 = Password.contains("asad123");

    if (email1){
      Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (password1) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "The method worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect Username/Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_project2);
  }
}
```

Somebody plz help!!
THanks in advance...

Comment: You probably want to change `if(email) ... else if(password)` to `if(email && password)`. So you check that both need to be true for the check to work.

Comment: What is the exact error or problem you're having? Are you seeing an "incompatible types" message or what? If you don't indicate specifically what the problem is, then no one can help you.

Comment: Are emailEditText and passwordEditText in your view actually EditText views? Using.getText().toString() on an EditText is not the problem, but if these views are not EditText views...

Comment: Thanks alot to you all. After I posted the question I googled to find the answer amd noticed my code was right but error was because I forgot to add onclick on the button..                         and alsothanks schred I used and operator and it worked perfectly fine